# soap request issue

Tags: php, soap

```
POST /accountapi/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: staging.prepaidfinancialservices.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://accountapi.internal/CardInquiry"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <CardInquiry xmlns="http://accountapi.internal/">
      <sClientLogin>string</sClientLogin>
      <sClientPassword>string</sClientPassword>
      <CardNumber>string</CardNumber>
    </CardInquiry>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Above is the SOAP request but when i try to post it via my php code i am getting an error that "Couldn't resolve host 'accountapi.internal"...help me plzz

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', "1");
$a=fopen("test.xml",'r');
$mxml=fread($a,65536);
$url='http://accountapi.internal/CardInquiry';
$yt =curl_init($url);
$header =   "POST /accountapi/service.asmx HTTP/1.1 <br>";
$header .=  "Host: staging.prepaidfinancialservices.com <br>";
$header .=  "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 <br>";
$header .=  "Content-Length: ".strlen($mxml)."\r\n <br>";
$header .=  "SOAPAction: 'http://accountapi.internal/CardInquiry' <br>";
echo $header."<br><br>";
//exit; 


$header .=  $mxml;
curl_setopt($yt, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($yt, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($yt, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
curl_setopt($yt, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rxml=curl_exec($yt);
echo "sent\n$mxml\n<br>";
echo "received\n$rxml\n"; 
echo curl_error($yt);
 ?>
```

Here is my php code ....

Comment: Please add your PHP code as well. Otherwise your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the url `http://accountapi.internal/CardInquiry` belongs to some LAN & is publicly not available to use. So when ever you are calling this URL it's not getting any name server register for this address. so you are getting the message "Couldn't resolve host". Try putting IP Address i think it will work.

Comment: Here is the link for "http://accountapi.internal/CardInquiry" API ..https://staging.prepaidfinancialservices.com/accountapi/service.asmx?op=CardInquiry

Comment: Actually i am try to implement `prepaidfinancialservices.com` payment method in my website instead of paypall payment method.....and i am trying to use `prepaidfinancialservices.com` API 

and for card inquiry i want to post SOAP request like this....`https://staging.prepaidfinancialservices.com/accountapi/service.asmx?op=CardInquiry`